# Comparing previous array elements for Insertion Sort algorithm

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I'm working with insertion sort algorithm. As you know we need to compare array elements with previous array elements. I try to do this with nested loops:

```
scanf("%d", &size); //gets array size

int array[size];
int temp = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
} // Takes the index of array.

/*
 Sorting part begins.
 */

for (int j = size - 1; j <= 0; j--) {
    int pseudoJ;

    pseudoJ = j;

    while (1) {
        if (array[pseudoJ] < array[pseudoJ - 1]) {
            temp = array[pseudoJ];
            array[pseudoJ] = array[pseudoJ - 1];
            array[pseudoJ - 1] = temp;
            pseudoJ--;
        } else
            break;
    }  
}

/*
 * Sorting Par Ends.
 */
```

Assume that input is: `3(Array Elements)>3>2>1`,
I expected the output of `1>2>3` but the output is still `3>2>1`.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code using a debugger?

Comment: No, I didn't let me look with gdb..

Comment: Take a very good look at the boundary condition of your second `for` loop.

Comment: Yes, when I change few lines of code it compares the previous array element but did not compare with all the previous ones..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code has multiple problems:

- the outer loop exits immediately: the test should be `j > 0` instead of `j <= 0`.
- the inner loop should test `pseudoJ` to avoid accessing elements before the beginning of the array
- it would be simpler to increment the index `j` in the outer loop and decrement `i` in the inner loop. The name `pseudoJ` is confusing.

Comment: Thank you for contribution!